# Extracting the elements inside Math.max

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a way to extract the elements that I have passed to the Math.max function.

```
var maxi = Math.max(document.getElementById('textBox1').value,
document.getElementById('textBox2').value,
document.getElementById('textBox3').value,
document.getElementById('textBox4').value,
document.getElementById('textBox5').value);
```

I would like to get not only the number but also the element, like if 10 is the max number associated to the `document.getElementById('textBox1').value` extract that element.

Comment: Not if you want to use Math.max(). You should build an array and loop through it.

Comment: What do you mean by extracting it? It would be easy to overwrite the `Math.prototype.max` but it already returns a number. Where do you want the element to be returned to?

Answer (score 1):

In case `Math.max()` is not a requirement for you:

```
var elements = [document.getElementById('textBox1'),
              document.getElementById('textBox2'),
              document.getElementById('textBox3'),
              document.getElementById('textBox4'),
              document.getElementById('textBox5')];
var maxIndex = -1;
var maxVal = -Infinity;
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].value > maxVal) {
        maxVal = elements[i].value;
        maxElement = elements[i];
    }
}
```

After the loop, `maxVal` will have the maximum value, and `maxElement` will be the associated DOM element.

Comment: I didn't know about it and it's great. Thanks, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: This is what I get as element: [object HTMLInputElement] I am not receiving the name of the element. For instance document.getElementById('textBox2')

Comment: The maxElement variable is a DOM element. You can access all its usual DOM properties, so if you need the id you can simply do `maxElement.id` and obtain "textBox2".

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own method which instead is similar to `Math.max` method like this

```
function myMaxElement = function() {
  var elementWithMaxValue = null,
      maxValue = -Infinity;

  for (var  i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (arguments[i].value >= maxValue) {
         maxValue = arguments[i].value;
         elementWithMaxValue = arguments[i];
      }
  }

  return elementWithMaxValue;
```

}

Now call this method with all your arguments like this

```
var maxElement = myMaxElement(document.getElementById('textBox1'),
                        document.getElementById('textBox2'),
                        document.getElementById('textBox3'),
                        document.getElementById('textBox4'),
                        document.getElementById('textBox5'));

console.log(maxElement);
```

PS: I wrote this code on run so may be a type there. I used **arguments** which is an array-like object and received in all methods. [MDN documentation for arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Comment: You are most welcome..If any of the answers solve your query please consider upvote and mark as answered. Not asking to choose me but whichever answer you feel helped you and was quickest :)

Comment: @nnnnnn I didn't know such a variable exists. Good suggestion :) WIll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `x.y` to a function as parameter you don't pass any information regarding `x`. To avoid this issue, you need to pass x and a way to access y from x. One example could be this one:

```
function myMax(f) {
  var maxEl = arguments[1];
  var maxVal = f(maxEl);


  for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    if (maxVal < f(arguments[i])) {
      maxEl = arguments[i];
      maxVal = f(maxEl);
    }
  }
  return { element : maxEl, value: maxVal }
}

// usage
var res = myMax(function(el) { return +el.value; }, 
                document.getElementById('textBox1'), 
                document.getElementById('textBox2'), 
                document.getElementById('textBox3'), 
                document.getElementById('textBox4'), 
                document.getElementById('textBox5'));

console.log('Max Element : ', res.element, ' with value : ', res.value);
```

Comment: I tried but the element result is not for instance document.getElementById('textBox1')

Comment: I converted the values to number :). Try again please.